# Broken Image Replace using http response headers

Tags: image, http, http-headers

I want to hide the broken image icon, but the image server that i'm using doesn't throw a 404 page, instead it redirects it to their alternative image, so I can't use the conventional onerror method.
This method works well if the server throws a 404 page in response.

```
<html>
<body> 
<div><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg" alt="image" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in conditions like, where image URL is: http://tinypic.com/someimage.jpg
the above method won't work. because this is a 302 response, which redirects it to some other image. I want to hide that as well.
Is that possible to somehow use http response as condition to display/hide image.

Here are http headers of the above image:

```
$ curl -I http://tinypic.com/notfound.jpg
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache
Location: http://tinypic.com/images/404.gif
Expires: Fri, 21 Mar 2014 21:33:07 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 217
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 21 Mar 2014 21:28:07 GMT
X-Varnish: 1535787681
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Varnish-Server: den2tpv01
X-Cache: MISS
```

Now, I think HTTP/1.1 302 Found can be used in someway. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go, the simple solution:**

```
<img src="www.google.com/noanyimage.png" width="200px" height ="200px" onerror="this.src ='';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using php...

```
<?PHP 
$url = "http://tinypic.com/notfound.jpg"; //Image link here
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($status_code==302 or $status_code==301 or $status_code==404){
  echo "no image found"; 
}
else {
echo '<img src="'.$url.'" />';  
}
curl_close($ch);

?>
```